# Set KeyPressed event for a TextField in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, stage

I have number of `TextField` objects inside a pop up window called dialog (type : `Stage`).

I am trying to define an action handler for them which aims to close the stage once the escape button is clicked on the key board.

Here is my function for the stage closer :

```
public void escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode keyCode , Stage dialog){
    if (keyCode == KeyCode.ESCAPE ){
        dialog.close();
        System.out.println("escape got called");
    }
}
```

and the following is where I call it :

```
textUsername.setOnAction((event) -> {escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode.ESCAPE ,dialog );});
textAddress.setOnAction((event) -> {escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode.ESCAPE ,dialog );});
textwp.setOnAction((event) -> {escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode.ESCAPE ,dialog );});
textState.setOnAction((event) -> {escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode.ESCAPE ,dialog );});
textloginName.setOnAction((event) -> {escapeKeyPressed(KeyCode.ESCAPE ,dialog );});
```

The problem is that the function doesn't get called.

Any idea how can I fix that? It's woth mentioning that the function by itself works fine if I replace the caller out of `setOnAction();`

Comment: If you have a Dialog you should consider using the Alert (javafx.scene.control.Alert) class, with ButtonType.CANCEL. This way you'll get a correctly labeled button in the correct order of the OS the application is running on AND Esc will (on platforms where this is considered to be the default behaviour) close the dialog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`setOnAction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-) documentation for `TextField` states:

> The action handler associated with this text field, or null if no action handler is assigned. **The action handler is normally called
>   when the user types the ENTER key.**

Therefore, `escapeKeyPressed` will be executed on `Enter` key press. What will happen now: if you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, it will call this method with `KeyCode.ESCAPE`, therefore it will close the dialog.

Use [`setOnKeyPressed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setOnKeyPressed-javafx.event.EventHandler-) rather than `setOnAction`:

> Defines a function to be called when this Node or its child Node has
>   input focus and a key has been pressed.

Rather than pass `KeyCode.ESCAPE`, pass the `KeyCode` of the [`KeyEvent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) what you can get with `getCode()`:

```
textUsername.setOnKeyPressed(event -> escapeKeyPressed(event.getCode(), dialog));
```